# What kind of Wi-Fi security protocol does not use encryption?

Tags: network, wifi, wireless

I need to sniff HTTP packet over the WiFi network. What kind of WiFi security protocol does not use encryption? I mean if I capture the WiFi packets, no effort required to decrypt wireless packets and get the HTTP packet data.

Comment: If the network is open then there is no encryption, then there's WEP, WPA and WPA2 all three of those encrypt traffic.You can always capture the encrypted packets then decrypt them later in wireshark when you have the passphrase.

Answer (score 3):

Just turn off the security and switch it to an open wifi network. There's no encryption at all on those.

If you still want authentication for egress, but not encryption, you could use a gateway similar to the ones used on free wifi portals.

Comment: Even when encryption is enabled, you should still be able to sniff the network as long as you are authenticated to the network (unless they are using EAP modules which provide end-point encryption)

Answer (score 2):

Polynomial and Lucas are both right. For an authorized user of the network, except for special (and usually enterprise-level) implementations, sniffing HTTP traffic over WiFi as cleartext should not be difficult regardless of what encryption (or lack thereof) is being used. Most of the common WiFi encryption protocols today are weak in this manner.

However, it's possibly also important to ask why you *really* need to do this over WiFi in the first place. A properly placed sniffer on the wired side of the network doesn't *need* to worry about WiFi encryption protocols - all data sent over Ethernet is in the clear, unless encrypted by a higher-level protocol (e.g.: HTTPS).